# How to host Java application on any cloud service (AWS, Azure, etc.)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, azure, sockets, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a client-server application that is working 100% when using localhost. I am using sockets to communicate between the two applications. All I want to do is host my server application on one of the popular cloud service providers, but I am having issues. All I need is some service that will start the application with "java -jar server.jar" and will allow my client to connect via their public DNS and/or IP address. I tried using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but it appears to want me to use HTTPS, and many of the various websites I find only want to discuss web apps and HTTPS.

Comment: You can certainly spin up an EC2 Linux instance on AWS and open an HTTP port, all in under 5 minutes time.  Not sure about Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

This is where something like Docker really shines. All you need to do is create a empty file named `Dockerfile` and copy and paste the following.

```
FROM java:8-jre

ADD ./build/libs/${JAR_FILE} /app/
CMD ["java", "-Xmx200m", "-jar", "/app/${JAR_FILE}"]
```

Replace `${JAR_FILE}` with the actual jar you want to run. Then you can build this running `docker build .`

With a working docker image it's trivial to push to DockerHub (or any repository) and run it on your server.

AWS, DigitalOcean, etc all offer basic servers with docker installed and ready to go.

This should point you in the right direction, if not give you the direct answer you're looking for.